# Aptana - jump from an HTML element to its CSS styling?

Tags: html, css, aptana

Is there a way in Aptana to jump from an HTML element to its CSS styling (embedded, if there is one, or to an external CSS file in the project's folder)?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry there's nothing like that on the market :(

Sublime does have a functionality like that but it isn't compatible with SASS or LESS 
https://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=4397